Conflict between Webflux global error handling DefaultErrorWebExceptionHandler and Controller Advice
I have DefaultErrorWebExceptionHandler to handle global errors.
For an api call with invalid input, GlobalErrorWebExceptionHandler was handling the requests.
Now I introducted, ExceptionHandling annotated with @ControllerAdvice to handle few other errors.
But after introducing ExceptionHandling control is going to one of the inherited methods in ProblemHandling.
How to resolve this conflict between GlobalErrorWebExceptionHandler and ExceptionHandling?

@Component
@Order(-2)
public class GlobalErrorWebExceptionHandler extends
        DefaultErrorWebExceptionHandler {

    public GlobalErrorWebExceptionHandler(ErrorAttributes errorAttributes,
                                          WebProperties webProperties, ObjectProvider<ViewResolver> viewResolvers,
                                          ServerProperties serverProperties,
                                          ServerCodecConfigurer serverCodecConfigurer, ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        super(errorAttributes,webProperties.getResources(), serverProperties.getError(), applicationContext);
        setViewResolvers(viewResolvers.orderedStream().collect(toList()));
        setMessageWriters(serverCodecConfigurer.getWriters());
        setMessageReaders(serverCodecConfigurer.getReaders());
    }

    @Override
    protected RouterFunction<ServerResponse> getRoutingFunction(
            ErrorAttributes errorAttributes) {

        return RouterFunctions.route(
                RequestPredicates.all(), this::renderErrorResponse);
    }

    @Override
    protected Mono<ServerResponse> renderErrorResponse(
            ServerRequest request) {

        Map<String, Object> errorPropertiesMap = getErrorAttributes(request,
                ErrorAttributeOptions.defaults());

        return ServerResponse.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(errorPropertiesMap));
    }
}



@Component
public class GlobalErrorAttributes extends DefaultErrorAttributes {

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getErrorAttributes(ServerRequest request, ErrorAttributeOptions options) {
        Map<String, Object> map = super.getErrorAttributes(request, options);
        map.put("status", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        map.put("message", "please provide a name");
        return map;
    }

}

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.zalando.problem.spring.webflux.advice.ProblemHandling;


@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandling implements ProblemHandling {
// handler methods
}



I have resolved the issue by redirecting the selected exceptions from ExceptionHandler to GlobalErrorWebExceptionHandler.
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandling implements ProblemHandling {

    @ExceptionHandler
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<Problem>> handleResponseStatusException(
            final ResponseStatusException exception,
            final ServerWebExchange request) {
        throw exception;
    }
}


